# is session.isNew() a safe way to check if a user is authroized to be on a page with java and spring

Tags: java, spring, session

I just want to double check to make sure that a user is allowed to be at page.

Previously I have been pulling the userName out of the session and seeing if that value is null. This is fine, but I was just wondering if isNew() would have the same results or if there might be some reason that a user could have a forged or previous session.

From reading about the method I feel like it would work just fine to use this way, but want to make sure I am not missing something.

I am doing this validation in the back with Java. The front end will be doing it's own validation too, using JS I imagine, it's more just an extra check I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: No. The session would be new if you browsed to that page as your first action on the site. Why aren't you using CMA?

Comment: so wouldn't that have the desired result then? User would browse to page, session would be new, i would detect that it is new and not allow them into the page. I am doing using CMA because, well, I do not know what it is. 

Learning as I go here.

Comment: Container Managed Authentication. You tell the servlet container what your roles are and where to find them per user, and what roles are required for what pages. Mostly done in `web.xml`. You should not attempt to roll this yourself.

Comment: If you are using Spring, I would check out Spring Security, it has a built in CSRF filter, Session Fixation Protection along with Authorization and Authentication.

Comment: @John Looking into Spring security, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In reading a few books such as PHP Hacks and Web Site cookbook, and MySQL, their common strategy is that every single page that can be accessed by a client should check for a valid session ID, a server event sequence ID, the users site status and the users role.
The site status (in SQL server) is usually: 'is_owner', 'is_creator', 'is_admin', 'is_member', 'is_new', 'is_suspended', 'is_banned'.
The entries for 'Role' is simular but pertains to a members role.
If a member comes out of suspension they may get back their status and role.
Roles can be: 'is_owner', 'is_creator', 'is_supervisor', 'is_manager', 'is_boss', 'is worker', etc.
Each page checks these 4 categories against the database to make sure the packet was not hijacked, or a sudden rise in rank, or they are a member again when they had been banned.
This does not include other fields such as permission to view or join chat or a group, but if that page offers that option it needs to confirm it with the database first.
The steps to accessing a page may involve several pages of query before the client is granted access. Checking one item to grant access to all is asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree with EJP above. You have a monster of a project so you need custom software for the pages and the DB management, to keep it all in order. You should consider hiring help so this is not a 5 year project.